# How can I make IOS 11 Mapkit display indoor mapping

Tags: routes, maps, mapkit, ios11

I want to display the **indoor mapping** that has been done for the *Schiphol Airport in The Netherlands* on my own Map so i can draw routes around it.

All I can see is the **3D model** of the building with some points inside but I don't know how to make it show the **different floors** inside the building.

Is this even possible or is this a feature restricted only for Apple Maps?

Answer (score 1):

The indoor maps is a feature that is not public for third party developers. Apple creates these maps and adds them to the app on their own pace.

**Update**
Information about indoor maps on Apple‘s Developer site on [maps](https://developer.apple.com/maps/) where you can send a request.

Comment: Do you have any official source of this information?